# Where are libvirt "saved states/snapshots" stored?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I have a .qcow2 image, and I can port it easily to a different computer. But I'd also like to port its saved state. Where are they stored?

I'm on Manjaro/Arch.

Answer (score 5):

You can view the location of the VM block devices by using the following command:

```
virsh domblklist VM1
```

The whole backing chaing of the block device can be seen:

```
qemu-img info --backing-chain /var/lib/libvirt/images/VM1.snap1
```

The clone procedure was perfectly desribed here: 
[Clone KVM virtual machine with snapshots](https://serverfault.com/questions/769867/clone-kvm-virtual-machine-with-snapshots)